# How to call function of JavaScript from servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am new to web development. I have an external JavaScript file which has a function to show
a prompt with error details. I need to pass the error message to the function. I have written contoller in servlet.

How to call the function of that JavaScript file from my servlet.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. JavaScript is executed in the en-user's browser. A servlet is executed on the server. Rethink about what you really want to do.

Comment: @JBNizet I think we can call JS from servlet. We can send responce to the browser and in that itself we can create script to be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to call a java script function from a servlet. Rather, you can print javascript code using

`response.getOutputStream().println("[javascript code]");`

into the browser and then the javascript function will be executed in the browser.

Comment: You have to use script tag along with your java script code like response.getOutputStream().println("<script type='text/javascript'>var ps = document.getElementsByClassName(\"messages\");" + "ps.innerHtm=\"DONE\";</script>");

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve similar kind of behavior by using following method. While sending response itself you can provide JS events.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' name='Button' value='Search' onclick=\"searchRecord('"+ argument + "');\"></td></tr>");
```

So when you click on Search button, search record method of JS will be called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that a servlet runs in the webserver, not in the webbrowser and that JS runs in the webbrowser, not in the webserver. The normal practice is to let the servlet forward the request to a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) file which in turns produces HTML/CSS/JS code which get sent to the webbrowser by the webserver. Ultimately, all that HTML/CSS/JS code get executed in the webbrowser.

To achieve your (somewhat strange, tbh) functional requirement, just let the forwarded JSP conditionally render the particular script call. For example as follows with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:if>`, assuming that you've collected and set the errors as `${errors}` in JSON array format:

```
<c:if test="${not empty errors}">
    <script>displayErrors(errors);</script>
</c:if>
```

Or let JSP assign it as a JS variable and let JS handle it further. Something like:

```
<script>
    var errors = ${errors};

    if (errors.length) {
        displayErrors(errors);
    }
</script>
```

As to the requirement being strange, if you're forced to use JS to display messages, that can only mean that you're using an `alert()` or something. This is very 90's and not user friendly. Just let JSP produce the HTML accordingly that they're put next to the input fields, or in a list on top of the form. [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) has a hello world example which does exactly like that.